# What to do with XSD and XSDL for SOAP - Java

Tags: java, soap

So a guy send me a xsd and xpdl and told me to make requests to a SOAP gateway using this in Java.

What am I supposed to do with this? Load it or something? Can someone explain?

Any advice?

Comment: google "generate java code from xsd". After that ask him what address should he send requests to: it requires server to run and accept those requests.

Comment: I can't do that. This is enterprise code

Comment: You can't autogenerate from xsd? Even if it is enterprise code, you should have access to internet and this is only "external" endpoints. This is no secret. If you don't have access to internet, ask the guy to generate code for you, since you can't.

Comment: The address endpoints are on  a local network

Comment: code is generated regardless of where the endpoint is. You need to set address, after code is generated, yourself

Answer (score 1):

You should receive a WSDL as well. Using WSDL then you can generate soap client in java.

Soap client is like a library which act as local set of classes and methods. You can use those to call operations to execute on SOAP gateway. Its like you are calling a function locally but when executed, it will run on the SOAP gateway (remote server) where this function logic is implemented and hosted.

Comment: How can I generate that ? I tried with eclipse but it generated thousands of files

Comment: apparently he "can't" whatever it means. But this is correct answer to the question.

Comment: tell your 'guy' to send you WSDL file.

Comment: I have all the WSDL and XSD files.

Comment: follow this link
https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

Comment: flopcoder is right, follow the instruction then from the list. Use wsdl2java -- this creates the java soap client from WSDL as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

wsdl contains SOAP endpoints and xsd for data validation and description. Suppose you have a SOAP request like this

```
<message name = "SayHelloRequest">
      <part name = "firstName" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <message name = "SayHelloResponse">
      <part name = "greeting" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <portType name = "Hello_PortType">
      <operation name = "sayHello">
         <input message = "tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
         <output message = "tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>
```

here **SayHelloRequest** is request definition and **SayHelloResponse** is response defination. and Now suppose you have an Java Plain Object and then you need to define this on XSD like below code

```
<xs:element name="Person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

you can define in XSD datatypes and its validation.

For simplicity **xsd** validate document and metadata anotherway **WSDL** is to describe the webservice location and operations. you can generate java classes from wsdl and yu can follow this link
https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

Comment: So I need to open the files with notepad and start creating the SOAP envelopes manually? Isn't there a way to automate this?

Comment: @user10628262 it can be generated

Comment: you can generate eclipse and follow this link
https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html